# How to get XP style alt-tab on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Is there anyway in windows 7 to change the behavior of alt-tab so that it acts like it did in XP?

What I want is for it to show the icon of the program, not a thumbnail of the window.  Most of the thumbnails look alike and its really hard to instantly tell which is which like I could on XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows 7 Easter Egg Shows the XP Alt-Tab Prompt](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5200/stupid-geek-tricks-windows-7-easter-egg-shows-the-xp-alt-tab-prompt/)

[image]

Just in case you aren’t using Windows 7 yet, the normal Alt-Tab window in Win7 is big, transparent, and really a big improvement on that ugly XP version.

[image]

To trigger the old XP style one, you’ll need to do the following:

Hold down the Left (or Right) Alt key.
Press and release the other Alt key.
Keep holding down that first Alt key, and then press Tab.
And Voila! The ugly old XP-style one will show up.

[image]

Comment: You might call it ugly, but the first screen shot shows 28 icons most of which are a white box with a small icon in the corner. It takes more effort to visually distinguish them from each other.  The XP style just shows the icon, and I can immediately see the icon I'm looking for.  Is there a way to turn this feature on permanently in win7?

Comment: Answer was in the post's comments.  And I now see that it was the post saying XP style was ugly, not you :)

Comment: Ur not going to give me a +1?

Comment: Hold ur horses.. my 1st question on SU, so I had to register and etc.  Not enough rep to +1, but have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the comments following the post linked above

"Ahh, here it is:
In HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer add a DWORD with name AltTabSettings and Value 1"

Thats much better, now I can see what is in the alt-tab list again.  That Aero style alt-tab was really bad for my eyes.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it 1) doesn't require extra key-presses and 2) is permanent.